# Reuse variable name when inserting an Xcode snippet

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, code-snippets

I'm making a snippet to make `UILabel`s faster. In this snippet I really just want to set the variable name once and then use it later when setting the color and background color. How can I reuse what I set in `<#labelName#>` so I don't have to write it for every attribute I alter?

```
UILabel *<#labelName#> = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#x#>, <#y#>,<#width#>, <#height#>)];
<#labelName#>.textColor = <#UIColor#>
<#labelName#>.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I think it's not possible. File a proposal to bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Used to be possible pre-Xcode 4 -- one placeholder was allowed to be "capturing" (denoted `<#!labelName!#>`); you could write the variable name, select it, then trigger the snippet (I forget what they were called then). It would replace all `<#!labelName!#>`s with the selected text. This would also be possible with scripting support. Like Shmidt says, file a bug.